# Pegar QueryString com NodeJS

Tags: node.js, http, express.js, socket.io

Estou precisando pegar a `QueryString` que está sendo passada para o servidor criado no **NodeJS**. Já tentei de várias formas mas não consigo pegar os parâmetros **do** e **ph**. Sou iniciante no NodeJS e o código que tenho é:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , fs = require('fs')
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

var porta = 3000;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')

});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

  result = {
          ph: Math.random() * 100,
          DO: Math.random() * 100
        }

  /*socket.emit('dados', {
    valor: result
  });*/

  socket.broadcast.emit('dados', {
    valor: result
  });


});


server.listen(porta, function(){
  console.log("Servidor rodando na porta "+porta+". Aperte CTRL+C para finalizar a conexão.");
});
```

Preciso pegar esses dados que vão ser passados pela QueryString e jogar no `json` **result** no lugar dos `Math.random() * 100`

Comment: De onde vem essa _querystring_? como envias isso no browser?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/?do=30&pa=10 ... Preciso pegar essas 2 querystring no app.js que é o código que postei, mas não sei qual modulo eu uso e como usar

Comment: A API é `var foo = req.query.nomeDaChave;`, e podias fazer assim: https://jsfiddle.net/t4gpf3ys/ o problema é que assim usuários diferentes mudam essa global... esses valores de `do` e `ph` são estáticos ou mudam?

Comment: @Sergio eles mudam de 5 em 5 segundos

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei [uma ideia aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29934170/2256325) que pode ser aplicada aqui:

```
var ligacoes = {};
var queryString = {};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    queryString.do = req.query.do;
    queryString.ph = req.query.ph;
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    if (!ligacoes[socket.id]) ligacoes[socket.id] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(queryString));
    var result = {
        ph: ligacoes[socket.id].ph,
        DO: ligacoes[socket.id].do
    }

    socket.emit('dados', {
        valor: result
    });

    socket.broadcast.emit('dados', {
        valor: result
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        delete ligacoes[socket.id];
    });
});
```

Desta maneira é criada uma entrada para cada socket num objeto `ligacoes`, e cada vez que essa entrada fôr criada ele copia os valores que `queryString` tem e mantêm-os para essa ligação.